# Sharepoint & Azure: msoidcliL.dll missing

Tags: sharepoint, azure, dll

I'm trying to deploy an application to Azure Websites that uses the Sharepoint Client Object Model (Sharepoint SDK 2013) to read data from a Sharepoint instance.

Everything works fine when I run it locally (with the Sharepoint SDK installed), but when I deploy it to Azure Websites and try to run it, I get `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: msoidcliL.dll`.

Obviously, it's because there's no Sharepoint SDK installed on the Azure server.

Is there any way to get this running on Azure Websites?

I already tried to copy the DLLs into the `~/bin` directory (I tried with both 32 and 64 bit versions), which didn't change to error at all. I googled a few posts from people that had a similar problems, but I wasn't able to find any hint or solution so far :(

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm think this is not possible.

As workaround you may try to change variable in class ClientUtility.s_setupDirectory using reflection, something like that:

```
var path = Server.MapPath("/") + "bin\\";
logger.Info("Server Path:" + path);
var field = typeof(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientUtility)
              .GetField("s_setupDirectory", 
                        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
field.SetValue(null, path);
```

But you may run into other problems

UPDATE: Please use SharePoint Client Components V16, it will work.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there are other problems :( I wasn't able to get it to run, because it seems to require even more DLLs or /and also certain registry keys.

I agree with you that it seems not possible to get the Client Object Model to run on a machine that does not have the SDK installed.

Comment: Additional info http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2013/03/18/sharepointonlinecredentials-and-msoidclil-dll-file-not-found-exception/

Answer (score 2):

Just use Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client & Runtime Dlls of V 16. You won't get error.